# Reader Writers prob using Semaphores in Java-wrong thread name, unable to run concurrently and show concurrency

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

While this might look like a repeat question, there is not *ONE* correct working implementation of the Reader Writer's problem in the internet using semaphores in Java. The closest I found was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8124481/solving-readers-writers-using-java-semaphores) where an alternative is given as the answer but not using semaphores.

I am new to multi-threading in Java so please bear with me. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

class ReaderWritersProblem {

    static Semaphore readLock = new Semaphore(1);
    static Semaphore writeLock = new Semaphore(1);
    static int readCount = 0;

    static class Read implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public synchronized void run() {
            try {
                readLock.acquire();
                readCount++;
                if (readCount == 1) {
                    writeLock.acquire();
                }
                System.out.println("Thread "+Thread.currentThread().getName() + " is READING");
                Thread.sleep(1500);
                System.out.println("Thread "+Thread.currentThread().getName() + " has FINISHED READING");
                readLock.release();
                readCount--;
                if(readCount == 0) {
                    writeLock.release();
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    static class Write implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public synchronized void run() {
            try {
                writeLock.acquire();
                System.out.println("Thread "+Thread.currentThread().getName() + " is WRITING");
                Thread.sleep(2500);
                System.out.println("Thread "+Thread.currentThread().getName() + " has finished WRITING");
                writeLock.release();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Read read = new Read();
        Write write = new Write();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(read);
        t1.setName("thread1");
        Thread t2 = new Thread(read);
        t2.setName("thread2");
        Thread t3 = new Thread(write);
        t3.setName("thread2");
        Thread t4 = new Thread(read);
        t4.setName("thread4");
        t1.run();
        t2.run();
        t3.run();
        t4.run();
    }
}
```

I am creating 4 threads, 3 for reading and 1 for writing. However, the output is as such:

> Thread main is READING
>  Thread main has FINISHED READING
>  Thread
>   main is READING
>  Thread main has FINISHED READING
>  Thread main
>   is WRITING
>  Thread main has finished WRITING
>  Thread main is
>   READING
>  Thread main has FINISHED READING

The thread name being returned is 'main'. Also, all of these are seemingly not being executed concurrently. How do I *correct* this implementation of Reader Writers problem using Semaphores only? Using `ReentrantReadLock` etc would simply this but beat the purpose of the question, which clearly says implement the problem using semaphores. Thanks

Edit: Also, *HOW* do I show multiple threads reading? I am getting the execution results one by one.

**EDIT: CORRECTED CODE:** I have corrected the algorithm. Would like some review on this.

```
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

class ReaderWritersProblem {

    static Semaphore readLock = new Semaphore(1);
    static Semaphore writeLock = new Semaphore(1);
    static int readCount = 0;

    static class Read implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                //Acquire Section
                readLock.acquire();
                readCount++;
                if (readCount == 1) {
                    writeLock.acquire();
                }
                readLock.release();

                //Reading section
                System.out.println("Thread "+Thread.currentThread().getName() + " is READING");
                Thread.sleep(1500);
                System.out.println("Thread "+Thread.currentThread().getName() + " has FINISHED READING");

                //Releasing section
                readLock.acquire();
                readCount--;
                if(readCount == 0) {
                    writeLock.release();
                }
                readLock.release();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    static class Write implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                writeLock.acquire();
                System.out.println("Thread "+Thread.currentThread().getName() + " is WRITING");
                Thread.sleep(2500);
                System.out.println("Thread "+Thread.currentThread().getName() + " has finished WRITING");
                writeLock.release();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Read read = new Read();
        Write write = new Write();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(read);
        t1.setName("thread1");
        Thread t2 = new Thread(read);
        t2.setName("thread2");
        Thread t3 = new Thread(write);
        t3.setName("thread3");
        Thread t4 = new Thread(read);
        t4.setName("thread4");
        t1.start();
        t3.start();
        t2.start();
        t4.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your question is related to why this code is not executing concurrently. This is because you have to call the method t1.start() and not t1.run() (and correspondingly so for all your other threads). t1.run() will run the run() method in the context of main thread and not in a new thread.

And I don't see the point of synchronized methods when you are already guarding the code with a binary semaphore. Two threads will not be able to simultaneously acquire a binary semaphore and as long as threads are not releasing the semaphore blindly your code will be safe. This defeats the whole prupose of having multiple reader threads.

Updated for the new question in comment - If you want multiple reader threads to access the same section then you should not use a binary semaphore but a semaphore with a bigger value (preferably equal to the number of reader threads). All of these threads can acquire the semaphore and release them when they are done. Also special care must be taken to to not starve the  writer thread when many reader threads are active. This could be done in many ways - Just google for readers - writers problem and you will find out how you can do it.

Comment: That solves one part of the problem thanks. Please refer to the update question. How do I get the output to show concurrent threads reading?

Comment: Ok thanks. Also I want the output something like 'Thread 2 is reading, Thread 3 is reading, Thread 2 finished reading' etc to show that multiple threads can read at the same time. IN that case, I will have to change the upper limit of the `readLock` semaphore to > 1 correct? Also is the rest of the code OK?

Comment: I have updated the answer. But I still don't understand parts of your code like why you are trying to acquire a writer lock in a reader thread. So am holding on to general comments on your code.

Comment: I would like to know what the optimal changes to the code would be, if you have the time. Also, should I be using `AtomicInteger` for the `readCount` variable?

Comment: The writer lock is acquired in the reader thread because if the no. of readers are > 1, then the writer cannot access the critical section. I have referred to the pseudocode on wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writers_problem):